# Is there a total file number limit for box users?

Tags: box-api

We have a box Enterprise account and are looking at implementing a service account that will host a folder with restricted privileges for every user in the Enterprise. The top level will likely have 10s of thousands of folders (one for each user), though this could probably be broken up into sub folders, e.g. alphabetical to reduce the number of folders at a particular node.  No idea how much might be saved in each user folder.

- Is there a limit to the total number of objects (Folders/Files) for a single user (the service account)?
- What performance implications    might this present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our box support rep has informed us that there is a recommended object limit/user, (I am unable to provide the number as it is protected by NDA). The performance implications are not clear but prudence dictates that any such implementation would need to include mechanisms for:

- monitoring number of objects
- limiting per user objects
- generating new service accounts

We are looking into alternate approaches to our requirements.